# Вместо urldecode скачивается php-файл

Tags: php, apache

PHP код:

```
<?php
urldecode( '%111' );
?>
```

Вместо какой либо ошибки у меня скачивается PHP файл. Как можно "схватить" ошибку, в случае если параметр подменят? И как настроить *apache* на подобные случаи, когда вместо ошибки он "выкидывает" php файл с мусором?

Comment: В вашем коде ошибки нет. У вас может php помер, apache и отдает вам код файла?

Comment: @Visman, не весь код, а данную строку с какими-то "кракозябрями".

Answer (score 1):

У Вас не работает (точнее, про него не знает апач) интерпретатор php. Поэтому файл php апачем считается просто текстовым файлом, и возвращается Вам сервером.

Comment: Комментарии-то к вопросу прочитайте. Их там всего 2.